# How to minimize the query time in mysql

Tags: mysql

In my database I have table named fo_image_guestimage, It Contains more then 2,63,000 rows only. But when i trying to update only one content in that, it yakes too much of time (121.683ms)

My Table structure-
[image]

my query execution and its time

[image: my query execution and its time]

How to minimize the query time in mysql? My table type was InnoDB.

EDIT 1-

My DATABASE Size - 3.5 GB , fo_guest_image table size 2.8 GB

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `fo_guest_image` (
    `Fo_Image_Id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Fo_Image_Regno` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    `Fo_Image_GuestHistoryId` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Photo` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Doc1` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Doc2` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Doc3` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Doc4` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Doc5` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Doc6` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `Fo_Image_Billno` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Fo_Image_Id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=36857
```

**Query With Execution Time -**

```
select COUNT(Fo_Image_Regno) from fo_guest_image; Time: 11.483ms

select * from fo_guest_image where Fo_Image_Regno='G13603'; Time: 101.381ms

update fo_guest_image set Fo_Image_Regno='T13603' where Fo_Image_Regno='G13603'; Time: 144.360ms
```

I have tried a nonblob table: - fo_daybook Size 400 KB

**Query With Execution Time -**

```
select * from fo_daybook; Time: 0.144ms

select fo_daybok_Regno from fo_daybook; Time: 0.004ms

update fo_daybook set fo_daybok_Regno ='T13603' where fo_daybok_Regno ='G13603'; Time: 0.011ms
```

My Client Added 1000 rows per day in fo_guest_image. Now fo_guest_image table size 2.8 GB, surely it increase day by day. I am scary if the table has one day reach 10 G.B. Then what will happen to performance.

Comment: Create indexes on `fo_image_GuestHistoryId`?

Comment: How long does an update of a non-BLOB column takes? How many rows are ther in the table overall and with `fo_image_GuestHistoryId=0`? Are there _any_ indexes or constrains on this table?

Comment: @stoleg this is a non-BLOB column! there is no index in my table sir. fo_image_id is primary key that all

Comment: How does it takes for the same `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @stoleg I have tried select * from fo_guest_image. But It through memory exception. So I update select query for particular column

Comment: Do `Select fo_image_GuestHistoryID from fo_guest_image where fo_image_GuestHistoryID = '0'`. I think your update is not too slow.

Comment: this query takes Time: 11.462ms. // I think your update is not too slow// Are you sure sir.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short solution: add index on the column "Fo_Image_Regno"

Longer, but much better, solution: do not store images in the tables. Store only links to the images in the table. And then store images in local folders/directories on the system. It will be much better now and in the future

Comment: Actually I store the link in DB, and save the Files in Folder at before I knowing the Blob method in MySQL., Past one year ago i change it to BLOB. is the Blob in MySQL was worst? Is any other solutions for this. Or I want to step backward?

Comment: What you did before was the best. So you can go back and store links in DB and image files in local folders. The DB will be much faster when updating and making backups and managing your data in the future.

Answer (score -1):

My apologies for incorrect first unswer. I did not realise that you are updating a non-blob column. However all my reservations about using `BLOB` columns to store documents are valid.

Re this `UPDATE` statement updated 14119 rows. It had to read all 2.9 million rows find those 14k that match `WHERE` clause and only then update them.

Check how long a `SELECT` query will run. I'm sure it will be pretty close to timing of update statement. 2.9 mn rows is not a small dataset.

Adding an index on `fo_image_GuestHistoryID` will speed up this query, but slightly slow down `inserts` into the table. Also it will take some time to create the index.

Index will speed it up, but there costs of having an index. In case of adding 1000 ros a day benefits of indes should outweight its costs.

Comment: Is any alternative for Blob? And How to locate the row to MySQL?

Comment: EXPLAIN update command not work in MySQL 5.1.36. Is any Alternative there?

Comment: Have you considered storing paths in DB and files on the filesystem?

Comment: So you are told me to remove blob in my concept

Comment: I have tried a update query which affect single row. I update my question part. please see